# How do I completely remove Google Chrome apps (e.g. Postman) on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-shell, webapps

I backed up my home directory from Ubuntu 14.04, installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new PC, then restored my home directory.

I went ahead and installed the native app following [these instructions](https://blog.bluematador.com/posts/postman-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-1604/). Now I'm trying to remove the Chrome web app and I can't figure out how to uninstall it.

Both the Chrome app and the native app are showing up in my launcher - in fact, the Chrome app has an icon and the native app is missing its icon. But the Chrome app is not in Chrome's `chrome://extensions` page, so there's no option to uninstall.

I've searched my home directory for references to Postman (`find ~ -iname "*postman*"`) and moved my `~/.config/Postman` directory. This did remove my Postman history but did not remove the Postman Chrome app (not that I really expected it to).

How can I completely remove the Postman web app?

**Edit**

I fixed the missing icon image; the directions I followed had the wrong path for the icon image. The good news is that the old icon and the new have slightly different colouring, so I can tell them apart. But I'd still prefer to just have one.

Comment: could you upload screenshots that you can't find app in chrome?

Answer (score 20):

Hover on any extension and click `manage extensions` and then search postman and choose remove.

This will remove web app postman from Chrome.

edit 1: reply to comment.

If you can't see chrome extension, then click on any extension, then the `extension` menu opens where you can search for `Postman`, then click `remove`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the app is not showing up in Chrome. There is no option to remove the web app.

Comment: Then try a restart as this is installed from the extension area so don't know how we can help

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if you manage to solve this, I had the exact same problem: I looked for postman references with both `locate` and `find` commands and removed all of them but the application was still there... Finally, I found it:

It was in `~/.local/share/applications`, where you can find desktop files for different chrome extensions (with weird names). The one for Postman is: `chrome-fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop-Profile_X.desktop`, where the X depends on your profiles on chrome and for which of them you have the app installed.

Answer (score 6):

On my machine/in my Chrome, the Postman Chrome app was also not listed as an extension.

But then I switched the Chrome user to the one, I've used before, the Postman Chrome app appeared as extension and could be removed with a mouse click.

So maybe you've simply installed under another user, just like me...:)

Comment: Thanks MiK, it was easy to remove once you go through your profiles and work out which one was first to install it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a useful note for **Windows** users:

Once removing the app through your chrome browser, as described in a previous answer, the start menu entry for the legacy chrome extension will still show up for POSTMAN (and possibly make you use that instead of the non-deprecated native app).

To delete the lingering reference, delete the entry here:

```
C:\Users\{youruser}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Applications Chrome
```